# How to schedule HPA on Preemptible nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm facing an issue that I'm not sure how can be solved.

Today I have one GKE cluster with nodepool auto scaling enabled and using on-demand instances. But I want to change that and have a mixed approach with on-demand and preemptible to run replicas generated by HPA.

My issue is that I need to find a way to have at least of replica of my app deployment running on an on-demand node and the other replicas generated by HPA to be scheduled on the preemptible nodes.

So as I'm targeting my HPA to my deployment I need to create the scheduling logic on the deployment side.

So that's my config right now.

```
affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: service
                operator: In
                values:
                - {{ .Values.nameSpace }}-app
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: preemptible-node
                operator: DoesNotExist
      tolerations:
      - key: "preemptible-node"
        operator: "Equal"
        value: "true"
        effect: "NoSchedule"
```

The problem is that as I need to guarantee at least one replica running on the on-demand node and for that I set the node affinity to not match preemptible nodes, that end up scheduling the replicas on the on-demand nodes, instead of the preemptible where I set the toleration. But if I change the node affinity to `Exists` does not guarantee a replica on the on-demand nodes.

How can I solve this dilemma?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to include the [topologySpreadConstraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/) field on your deployment, see example below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 8
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      tolerations:
        - key: ...
          operator: ...
      nodeSelector:
      topologySpreadConstraints:
        - maxSkew: 1
          topologyKey: cloud.google.com/gke-preemptible
          whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
          labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: nginx
      containers:
        - name: ...
          image: ...
```

Or you may also re-configure [node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) as follows:

```
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - preference:
        matchExpressions:
        - key: cloud.google.com/gke-preemptible
          operator: Exists
      weight: 100 
tolerations:
- key: cloud.google.com/gke-preemptible
  operator: Equal
  value: "true"
  effect: "NoSchedule"
```

Comment: Hey Ron, But those changes look like related to scheduling on preemptible nodes only, but I want to ensure that at least 1 replica always runs on a non-preemptible node, that why I added the `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`

Comment: Hi, I think you can use topologySpreadConstraints in which node labels of preemptible and non-preemptible are same and will be put to topologykey. You are right with requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution, you can use multiple nodeSelectorTerms as per [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity:~:text=multiple%20terms%20in-,nodeSelectorTerms,-associated%20with%20nodeAffinity).